# What does the critical stat do?

Tags: the-evil-within

My understanding of the critical stat of weapons is that it affects the percentage change that a headshot will insta-kill a haunted or haunted variant. That matches observations.

The part that confuses me is that the rifle has a critical upgrade tree too, and even on Akumu mode with no upgrades I've never seen a rifle headshot not insta-kill a haunted.

So, am I misunderstanding its use in other weapons? Or am I misunderstanding what it does on the rifle?